# Iptables not dropping packets?

Tags: iptables

I have super simple iptables rule:

```
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/16 -o ens34 -j MASQUERADE

iptables -F INPUT
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.3.2/32 -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.3.2/32 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -j ACCEPT
```

Which gives me:

```
root@ubuntu:/etc/init.d# iptables -L -n -v
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   36  4576 ACCEPT     all  --  *  *       192.168.3.2          192.168.0.0/16
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *  *       192.168.3.2          0.0.0.0/0
  183 16364 ACCEPT     all  --  *  *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

And yet traffic from 192.168.3.2 to Internet is passed, from that server:

```
root@ubuntu:/etc/init.d# tcpdump -i ens37 -n not port 22
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v[v]... for full protocol decode
listening on ens37, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
18:43:37.852396 IP 192.168.3.2 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 17, seq 1, length 64
18:43:37.858730 IP 8.8.8.8 > 192.168.3.2: ICMP echo reply, id 17, seq 1, length 64
18:43:38.854008 IP 192.168.3.2 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 17, seq 2, length 64
18:43:38.860361 IP 8.8.8.8 > 192.168.3.2: ICMP echo reply, id 17, seq 2, length 64
```

ip addr:

```
root@ubuntu:/etc/init.d# ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens34: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:00:a0:01 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff permaddr 00:0c:29:fb:bf:33
    altname enp2s2
    inet 95.x.x.x/26 brd 95.x.x.x scope global ens34
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fe00:a001/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: ens37: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:fb:bf:3d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp2s5
    inet 192.168.2.2/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global ens37
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fefb:bf3d/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

ip route:

```
root@ubuntu:/etc/init.d# ip route show
default via 95.x.x.x dev ens34 proto static
95.x.x.x/26 dev ens34 proto kernel scope link src 95.x.x.x
192.168.2.0/24 dev ens37 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.2.2
192.168.3.0/24 via 192.168.2.1 dev ens37 proto static
```

Getting insane.....What is wrong ? Why that traffic is not blocked ?

Thanks,

Comment: Could it be because INPUT chain is for the traffic that has the server itself as a destination? Look into the diff between INPUT and FORWARD.

Comment: i do not undestand you. INPUT is having a rule to drop that traffic no matter what the destination is. Moreover the first rule in INPUT chain is working fine, i have the hitcounts. It's just the second which is not working for Internet traffic (destination any). I have hit counts on the third rule, somehow not matching the second one.

Comment: What's there to not understand? If the destination of the traffic is not the server, and the server is to forward the traffic elsewhere, the INPUT chain is not gonna do you any good.

Comment: Since the traffic goes through the server, it ends up in the FORWARD chain where the default policy is ACCEPT.

Comment: wow, indeed you are correct jabbson ! when i moved all the rules from INPUT to FORWARD it all started to work fine. But i was pretty sure INPUT should also work here. Is not that first packets arrive on INPUT, then FORWARD and finally OUTPUT ?

Comment: Check out [this](https://stuffphilwrites.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/FW-IDS-iptables-Flowchart-v2019-04-30-1.png) diagram for understanding the flow.

Comment: Here is an [article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/a-deep-dive-into-iptables-and-netfilter-architecture) that goes into logic of how it works.

Comment: Alternate diagram: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netfilter#/media/File:Netfilter-packet-flow.svg